# Extract date only from pandas' datetime.datetime column

Tags: pandas

I am using pandas to read an excel file which contains date and time data. I decided to leave the conversion to defaults (no converts used). The date column was converted to datetime.datatime (e.g. 1970-08-31 00:00:00). i wanted to extract the date part w/o time. I used df['Date']=df['Date'].date() which did not work even though when i tried the same on individual entries of the date column it worked (e.g. df['Date'][1].date().
Any help is greatly appreciated.

EK

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```py
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date
```

To get the dates of a datetime series.

When you do `df["Date"][0].date` you are accessing the first item in `df["Date"]`, which is an datetime-like object which has the property `.date`. When you do `df["Date"].date` you are trying to access the date property of a pandas series, which has no property `.date`. By using `df["Date"].dt.date`, it is first returning the *Accessor object* for datetimelike properties of the Series values, `dt`, of which you can apply `.date` to.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried that which worked through using pandas to_datetime to convert the datetime.datetime columns which seems to me a duplication. why would the df['date'][2].date() works but df['date'].date() does not work on the whole series?

Comment: I have modified my question to explain why you have to first do `.dt` to access the `.date` property of a pandas series

Comment: Thank you Tom. I think i got it now. The conversion was to datetime.datetime which doesn't have attributes date or time. When i converted to datetime, everything works as it should. Thanks again.